# Does glibc2 version of the crypt function still use DES for alternative hashing methods?

Tags: passwords, cryptography, hash, linux, unix

I'm trying to understand how typical **Linux** distributions generate the password field for entries in `/etc/shadow`. I can't figure out what encryption algorithm is being used to produce the encrypted password string.

For example:

```
$1$CQoPk7Zh$370xDLmeGD9m4aF/ciIlC.
```

From what I understand, the first value `1` signifies that an **MD5** hashing method was used with the second value `CQoPk7Zh` as the salt. However, what was the encryption algorithm used to produce the final encrypted password string `370xDLmeGD9m4aF/ciIlC.`?

The [Linux man page for crypt(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) has a note for **glibc2**:

> If salt is a character string starting with the characters "*$id$*" followed by a string terminated by "$":
>
> *$id$salt$encrypted*
>
> then instead of using the DES machine, *id* identifies the encryption method used and this then determines how the
>   rest of the password string is interpreted.

I think the semantics are throwing me off: the manual says *id* specifies the **encryption method**, but it's specifying the **hashing method**.

I believe the process is working like this:

```
password ==> MD5(password+salt) ==> hash ==> encryption-algorithm(hash) ==> encrypted-pass
```

So how do I determine the encryption algorithm? Specifically, what encryption algorithm is used when the *id* is `6` (**SHA512**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no encryption algorithm involved. The use of “encryption” is a misnomer, due to the historical password hashing algorithm being based on DES, which is primarily used for encryption and known as such. `id` is in fact the hashing method, and all documentation should properly use the word “hash” throughout instead of “encrypt”.

For id = 1, the algorithm isn't MD5(password+salt), but a variation on MD5<sup>1000</sup>(salt+password). The fixed iteration count (large at the time it was introduced, but now tiny) is the main reason to deprecate this scheme (also, the custom variation).

With id = 6, SHA-512 is used, again with many iterations. Ulrich Drepper, GNU libc maintainer, has written a [description of SHA-2-crypt](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt) with a precise description and sample code.

I think all common `crypt` variants encode the hash in a base64 variant (not “the” base 64, but a slightly different set of 64 printable characters).

Comment: `crypt` encodes using a [variant of Base64](http://serverfault.com/a/499293). This can be verified in code: `static const char b64t[64] =
"./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";`

Answer (score 2):

I think they really mean hashing method for the hash in use. The format is:

> "$id$salt$hashed", where "$id" is the algorithm used (On GNU/Linux, "$1$" stands for MD5, "$2a$" is Blowfish, "$5$" is SHA-256 and "$6$" is SHA-512 ...)

the source of which is available [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd#Shadow_file).

I've just looked at [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) and it does indeed say "encryption method". These are definitely not encryption methods like DES, but rather "one way" hash functions.

Comment: Why is the resulting string `370xDLmeGD9m4aF/ciIlC.`? I would expect an **MD5** hash to consist of a series of hexadecimal digits, but this string does not fit that format.

Comment: @VilhelmGray I imagine they encoded the hash value in a range of printable characters. It looks like BASE64 but I could be wrong. Either way, encoding in just 0-9,A-F requires two bytes per byte of actual data and is therefore quite expensive to use.

Comment: Oh I see, so the process the process would probably be similar to: `pass ==> MD5(pass+salt) ==> encoding-func(hash) ==> encoded-hash`

Comment: @VilhelmGray yep. MD5(pass+salt) will just be an array of bytes, e.g. `uint8_t arr[20];` (adjust 20 for bits/8) and the encoded version will be too, just modified so that each byte is printable. Technically, you could just store it in the file unprintable (what you might call a binary file) but Unix configuration has always traditionally used readable text files.